# I am trying to do an order total t-sql

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to get the quantity from the order items table and the price from the products table then multiply them in @OrderTotal and the function will return the Order total. i am a student and was sick when the lecturer explained these please help :)

Code:

```
create function [worksheet02].[udf_getOrderTotal](@orderID Bigint)
    returns Bigint
    as
        begin
            declare @OrderTotal Bigint
            declare @quantity integer
            declare @price integer
            @quantity = (select quantity
                        from [worksheet02].[tbl_order_items]
                        where order_id = @orderID); 

            @price =    (select unit_price
                        from [worksheet02].tbl_order_items oitm
                        join[worksheet02].[tbl_products] prd
                        on(oitm.product_id =prd.product_id)
                        where oitm.order_id = @orderID);

            @OrderTotal = @quantity * @price;
            return @orderTotal;
        end;
    go
```

Error:

```
        Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure udf_getOrderTotal, Line 68
        Incorrect syntax near '@quantity'.
        Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure udf_getOrderTotal, Line 72
        Incorrect syntax near '@price'.
        Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure udf_getOrderTotal, Line 78
        Incorrect syntax near '@OrderTotal'.
```

Comment: `SET @quantity = ...`, `SET @price = ...`, `SET @OrderTotal = ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are just missing the set and select to set your variables. See example below:

```
  CREATE TABLE tbl_order_items
  (
  order_id int,
  product_id int,
  quantity int
  )

  INSERT INTO tbl_order_items
  Values (1,1,1)

  CREATE TABLE tbl_products
  (
  order_id int,
  product_id int,
  unit_price int
  )

  INSERT INTO tbl_products
  Values (1,1,2)

GO

create function dbo.[udf_getOrderTotal](@orderID Bigint)
returns Bigint
as
    begin
        declare @OrderTotal Bigint
        declare @quantity integer
        declare @price integer
        set @quantity = (select quantity
                    from tbl_order_items
                    where order_id = @orderID); 

        set @price =    (select unit_price
                    from tbl_order_items oitm
                    join tbl_products prd
                    on(oitm.product_id =prd.product_id)
                    where oitm.order_id = @orderID);

        select @OrderTotal = @quantity * @price
        return @orderTotal;
    end
go

select dbo.[udf_getOrderTotal](1)

    drop table tbl_products
    drop table tbl_order_items

go
```